# How to remove a broken contact

Tags: contacts, 6.0-marshmallow

I've got a broken contact on my phone. It was an imported contact and I tried to merge it with an existing one. But when I did it, the contact remained visible in my Contacts app. However it's broken: when I try to open/delete/edit/merge it, nothing happens.

I tried to google the solution but I only found guides about how to get *contacts from my broken phone* but not about getting *broken contacts from my phone*.

Comment: Try: 1. Merging contact on your G mail using *web browser* 2. Deleting that contact on phone 3. Sync G mail contacts